# Out of (2n+1) tickets consecutively numbered,three are drawn at random. The chance that the numbers on them are in A.P. is?

Tags: probability

A solution I saw states that "**Out of 2n+1 numbers,n+1 would be odd and n would be even or vice-versa. If we select any 2 of the n+1 numbers, the third number will be automatically decided so as to have the three in AP and the same reasoning would be valid if we select any 2 of the n numbers (for example, if we select 3 and 11, the third number has to be 7 OR if we select 6 and 14, the third number has to be 10).**" I am not getting the part where the third number has to be in AP if the sum of the other two is even. I am aware that sum of extrimities of an AP is even but why the third number would be in AP. Suppose I pick 4 and 12 as my first two numbers and then I pick 14. Now 4,12,14 certainly doesn't form an AP. So can somebody explain me the mechanism of the answer and of the statement in double quotes, intuitively.

Comment: One way is to make cases for each common difference.

Comment: The questions talks about (2n+1) cases, here n could be anything. How am I supposed to make the cases?

Comment: The statement in quotes seems to be saying that once the first two numbers are chosen, if they are both even or both odd then there is only one possible choice for the third number if they are to form an AP. However this is clearly not true as simple examples show. If you are just interested in solving the problem it might be best to ignore the quote.

Comment: @MichaelCohen . I was unable to do so. Please solve it if you can, thanks in advance.

Comment: What the quote should have said is: In any 3-term AP, the first and last elements have the same parity. Conversely, given any two elements of the same parity, they are the first and last elements of exactly one 3-term AP, because the middle term must be the average of the first and last terms.

Comment: Does the comment above of Andreas Blass give you any clue how to proceed?

Comment: @MichaelCohen No

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/out-of-2n1-tickets-consecutively-numberedthree-are-drawn-at-random-the-chance-that-the-numbers/                                  full question and solution can be seen here, chexk it out and tell me how it is getting solved.

Comment: Bhai yahan pe acha se samjhaya hai https://testbook.com/question-answer/out-of-2n-1-tickets-which-are-consecutively-num--5fc7848bd2b1ef2651401d59

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the bold part quoted in your post is not very clear. It appears that they are choosing two odd values or two even values specifically for the least and greatest values in the arithmetic progression. (This is why they break into cases of selecting $2$ of the "$n+1$ numbers" or $2$ of the "$n$ numbers"--namely two numbers of the same parity). Then of course the middle value is just the average of the two already chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand better through a small concrete example. Let's take $n=3,$ so $2n+1$ numbers $1-2-3-4-5-6-7$

If we choose **any** two odd numbers, we can always make an A.P. viz $1^23,1^35,1^47,3^45,3^57,5^67$

Similarly if we choose any two even numbers, viz $2^34,2^46,4^56$

Thus # of such A.Ps $= \binom{n+1}2 + \binom{n}2= N,\;$say

and number of possible triples $=\binom{2n+1}2= D,\;$say

On simplification it yields the formula $Pr = \dfrac{N}{D}= \dfrac{3n}{4n^2-1}$