# $2n+1$ numbered balls in box in arithmetic progression

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

> **We have $2n+1$ numbered balls in a box. Three balls are chosen randomly and simultaneously. Find the probability that the numbers are in arithmetic progression.**

---

My attempt to solve it:

I have defined $$S=\{\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} | x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \{1,...,2n+1\}, x_1 \not = x_2 \not = x_3\}. $$ Then, I have defined the mass function $p: S \rightarrow [0,1] $ so that for $ \overline x \in S$, $p(\overline x)=k=\frac{1}{Card(S)}$.
**Correction**: $Card(S)=\binom{2n+1}{3}$.

---

Note: $Card()$ means cardinal.

---

In consequence, $\forall A \in \mathcal{P}(A)=\sum_{\overline x \in A} k =...=\frac{Card(A)}{Card(S)}.$

Now, we define $A_d=\{\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\in S | x_2=x_1+d, x_3=x_2+d\}$ for $d>0$. Thus, the probability of the numbers being in arithmetic progression would be $ P(\cup_{d=1}^{2n+1} A_d)$. However, I am having trouble delimitating the range of $d$ so that $A\subseteq S$ and calculating the intersection between different '$A_d$'s.

---

I feel like there should be an easier way to calculate the probability but I really can't come up with it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393706/out-of-2n1-tickets-consecutively-numbered-three-are-drawn-at-random-the-chan/4393733#4393733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to follow your notation, as you are almost there.

As you stated, let's write

$$A_d = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in S : x_2 = x_1 + d, x_3 = x_2 + d\}$$

We want to remove the "$\in S$ " restriction, so we replace it with the definition of $S$:

$$A_d = \{(x_1, x_1 + d, x_1 + 2d) : x_1, x_1 + d, x_1 + 2d \in [1, 2n + 1]\}$$

Of course, since $d\geq 1$, we only need the final term in the A.P. to be in the interval:

$$A_d = \{(x_1, x_1 + d, x_1 + 2d) : x_1 \geq 1, x_1 + 2d \leq 2n + 1\}$$

Finally, let's rearrange the final condition:

$$A_d = \{(x_1, x_1 + d, x_1 + 2d) : x_1 \in [1, 2n - 2d + 1]\}$$

From this, clearly we have $|A_d| = 2n - 2d + 1$ (iff it's positive of course). Now since the sets $A_d$ are disjoint, We have

$$|A| = \left|\bigcup_{d=1}^n A_d\right| = \sum_{d=1}^n |A_d| = \sum_{d=1}^n 2n + 1 - 2d = n^2$$

Finally, simply divide by $Card(S)$ to get your answer!